# Function defined, but MyFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

`Person` is object with a `firstName` and a `lastName` properties.
I have a service which returns some `Person`.
In order to model `Person` in Typescript, I have created the following `Person.ts` class:

```
export class Person {

    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;

    get fullName(): string() {
        return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
    }

}
```

I'm able to retrieve an array of `Person` with the following code:

```
this.persons: Array<Person> = this.httpClient.get<Array<Person>>('http://url.of.my.service');
```

For every `Person` in `this.persons`, I'm able to get it's first name and last name, but I get the following error if I try to get it's full name: `person.fullName is not a function`.
What does it mean?

Comment: Why did you put brackets () after `string`? Maybe just remove.

Comment: try to call fullName without brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The obvious one is that `fullName` is not a function, it's a property, as such it should be accessed `person.fullName` not `person.fullName()`

The second problem is that `this.httpClient.get<Array<Person>>('http://url.of.my.service');` will not return instances of `Person` it will return objects that may have the fields of `Person` but will not be instances of `Person` and thus the property `fullName` will not exist as you have defined it on the objects returned by that call. (Also guessing it does not directly return an array, looks like an Angular service returning an `Observable`)

You will need to transform the object to an instance of the class, using `Object.assign` for example.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> get fullName()
> ```

It is a **getter**, not a regular function.

When you access the `fullName` property it will **implicitly** call the function and give you the return value (which is a string).

Trying to call `fullName()` will try to treat that string as a function, which it isn't.

If you had defined it **without** the `get`, then you could call `fullName()`.